# ASP.NET Core ODataController not found

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, odata

I'm trying to build a really simple odata service into an existing ASP.NET (.net5) api.

Using:

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.0-rc3" />
```

I thought it would be simple (I only need to support GET and Get-$count), but I must be missing something.

Here is what I have:

**Model:**

```
public partial class MySuspension
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
  
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
  
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
        
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Responder { get; set; }
        
        public long? UnblockPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using entity framework for the db-access, so the model class was generated for EF (hence some of the attributes).

**Startup:**

This is the basic order of the "Configure" method:

```
 app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseODataRouteDebug();  ///// <----
            
            app.UseODataQueryRequest();///// <----
            
            app.UseODataBatching();///// <----

            app.UseCors("InternalApplications");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

            UseSwagger(app);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });
```

And I register my controllers like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<MySuspension>("ActSus");
var model0 = builder.GetEdmModel();
 
services.AddControllers()
           .AddOData(opt =>
           {
                opt.AddModel("data",model0)
                  .Count().Filter().Expand()
                  .Select().OrderBy()
                  .SetMaxTop(null);
            });
```

The above setup works perfectly for "normal" api-methods, so there aren't any auth/cors issues.

**Controller:**

```
 public class AccountActionController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

        public AccountActionController(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_dbContext.AccountSuspensions);
        }
    }
```

From what I understand this should work. I've inherited from the OdataController - which (I think) means that I don't need to use any other attributes. I think even the HttpGet and EnableQuery attributes might be redundant.

When I run it though, the odata route-debug page shows ~/data and ~/data/$metadata as the only OData endpoints.

~/data/$metadata shows a proper XML document that defines my MySuspension object accurately.

The AccountActionController does not appear in either the Odata endpoint or in the non-odata endpoints!!!

Aaargh!!! Frustration!!!

I KNOW that I'm being an idiot, but I can't for the life of me see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The AccountActionController does not appear in either the Odata
> endpoint or in the non-odata endpoints!!!
>
> ```
> var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
> builder.EntitySet<MySuspension>("ActSus");
> var model0 = builder.GetEdmModel();
> ```

The issue relates the above code, since the Controller's name is `AccountAction`, you should change the entity set name from `ActSus` to `AccountAction`, code as below:

```
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
    builder.EntitySet<MySuspension>("AccountAction"); //change the name.
    var model0 = builder.GetEdmModel();

    services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt =>
        opt.AddModel("odata", model0)
            .Count().Filter().Expand()
            .Select().OrderBy()
            .SetMaxTop(null)
    );
```

Then the result like this:

[image]

If you want to change the request url, try to use the [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 RC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/).

Reference: [ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 Preview for .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-odata-8-0-preview-for-net-5/)

Comment: Just to add to this, I had the exact same issue - my controller was named correctly but because I had lazily copy/pasted code from a non-OData controller into my new (correctly named) OData controller - I still had my "Get All" method named `Index()` - it *must* be named `Get()`.

Comment: @JamesLove I'd upvote this comment a thousand times... This finally solved my issue (my Get method was named Query). Maybe you want to answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70410729/642579. I will remove my answer and accept yours.

Comment: Thanks, this saved a lot of time