# Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8: controller is not found by convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

As described in the [docs](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/master/docs/routing-overview.md), Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8 uses a convention to tie a controller to an entity set. They also provide a [sample](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/master/sample/ODataRoutingSample) that demonstrates this behavior.

However, I've spent several hours to set up a minimal OData API with a simple controller, but the controller is neither shown by the OData routing debug page ($odata) nor can it be accessed through the browser.

This is the model:

```
namespace TestOData8
{
  public class Dummy
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace TestOData8.Controllers
{
    public class DummiesController : ODataController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Query(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new Dummy() { Id = x }).AsQueryable());
        }
    }
}
```

And this code sets up the application (this is the .NET 6 way of setting this up; I've also tried .NET 5 without success):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;
using TestOData8;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(5)
        .AddRouteComponents(GetEdmModel())
    );


IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var bldr = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    bldr.EntitySet<Dummy>("Dummies");
    return bldr.GetEdmModel();
}

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseODataRouteDebug();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

I've asserted that

- the EDM model is registered (this $metadata endpoint shows the Dummy entity)
- the name of the controller matches the entity set (Dummies -> DummiesController)
- routing works for controllers that don't support OData
- setting the `EnableAttributeRouting` option to false doesn't change the behavior

What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was very simple: the name of the method in the controller must be "Get"; after changing the action name, the controller worked:

```
public class DummiesController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new Dummy() { Id = x }).AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

Thanks to @JamesLove for a small comment under another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68078863/642579).

Comment: No worries! A few hours on my end hopefully saved yours!